# RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'

Tags: python, machine-learning, arcpy, geopandas, pyproj

I'm trying to solve my issue in my own but I couldn't, I'm trying to run this code in every format you can imagine and in ArcGIS pro software it's the same I can't find this error message in any other issue. From similar issues, it seems some data files could be missing?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, box
import ast
from pyproj import Proj
```

```
paths = road_features.SHAPE.map(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)["paths"][0]))
pathLineStrings = paths.map(LineString)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(road_features,geometry=pathLineStrings)
#gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:3857'}
gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

i get this error

```
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

also i tried it in arcgis pro i got the same

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 443, in to_crs
    geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 304, in to_crs
    proj_in = pyproj.Proj(self.crs, preserve_units=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 362, in __new__
    return _proj.Proj.__new__(self, projstring)
  File "_proj.pyx", line 129, in _proj.Proj.__cinit__
```

```
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

Comment: I ran into an error on an Anaconda, Windows 10 installation in which the pyproj package's file datadir.py was pointing to the wrong location for the proj file `epsg`. (`.../Anaconda3\share\proj` instead of `...\Anaconda3\Library\share`). Editing datadir.py fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Interestingly, if I launch either JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator or Anaconda Prompt, rather than from an Anaconda Powershell Prompt, I get no errors! Shouldn't these all be the same?  Why is Anaconda Powershell Prompt messing up?

Comment: I have exactly this same problem. Works fine when starting jupyter from Miniconda prompt but not when starting from Miniconda Powershell prompt. Thanks for the tip, any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there an initial `crs` defined?
I ran into the same problem only when I passed only the epsg command:  `gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')`.

As you show

`my_geoseries.crs = {'init' :'epsg:3857'}`

should be the first step and then transforming to

`gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})`

If you are working in ArcGIS you could also check in the properties whether the initial epsg is defined ?

Answer (score 26):

to make sure this is pyproj error rather than geopandas.

```
import pyproj
pyproj.Proj("+init=epsg:4326")
```

if the above runtime error is the same, we can be sure this error is due to pyproj.

just `conda remove pyproj` and install it with pip.

```
pip install pyproj
```

at least this works for me.

Today(July 30), I resintalled from miniconda, `conda remove pyproj` did not work for me, instead I `pip uninstall pyproj` and `pip install pyproj` makes everything fine.

Comment: Thank you! Removing by conda, then pip install pyproj. It works for me.

Comment: In uninstalling pyproj, it may be easier to run `pip remove pyproj --force` to avoid uninstalling geopandas or other dependencies

Comment: Ran into the same problem, and I used `pip install --force-reinstall pyproj` to avoid `conda remove pyproj` which removes packages that depend on `pyproj` like `geopandas`

Answer (score 15):

The problem is problably within the pyproj instalation of Anaconda on Windows platform. Just like Stephen said, solution is to edit the path in "datadir.py" (located in ...Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyproj).

Correct path is ".../Anaconda3/Library/share". Make sure full path is complete (may contain username etc.). I also needed to change \ to /.
This change worked for me. Yes and after this change, it is necesary to restart Spyder (or whatever you use).

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Pycharm.
I had to use a combination of both Stone Shi's remark and Dorregaray's.

```
import pyproj
pyproj.Proj("+init=epsg:4326")
> RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

According to Stone Shi, the above proves that it's a pyproj err.
So I used Pycharm->Settings and reinstalled pyproj.
Then

```
import pyproj
pyproj.Proj("+init=epsg:4326")
> RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

So, it's a pyproj err *but* Pycharm->Settings reinstalling pyproj does not help me.

I then edited my C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyproj\datadir.py 
from:

```
pyproj_datadir="C:/Anaconda3\share\proj"
```

to Dorregaray's:

```
pyproj_datadir="C:\Anaconda3\Library\share"
```

Then test again:

```
import pyproj
pyproj.Proj("+init=epsg:4326")
>Process finished with exit code 0
```

No Runtime Error!

Then test on my

```
wgs84  = data.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4269'})
>Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

For me upgrading `pyproj` and `geopandas`, fixed this issue:

```
pip install pyproj --upgrade 
pip install geopandas --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Geopandas, try that (it should work) :

```html
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry=gdf['geometry'])
gdf.crs = {'init' :'epsg:2154'}
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init' :'epsg:4326'})
```

You should redefine well your geodataframe, 
then define the initial geo referential
and finally convert it in the good one.
Don't forget to drop the NaN if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

you can force reinstall pyproj from pip directly using

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyproj`

instead of uninstalling and reinstall again which will also uninstall all the dependent libraries

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error. I was working with Python version 3.6.3 and Geopandas version 0.4.0. It was solved by using the following instead of `df = df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})`:

```
df = df.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```