# "b'no arguments in initialization list" with pyproj, Pycharm, and Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pyproj

So I've been attempting to do a little GIS projection conversation for a project of mine, using some code I found online.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:8826')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = 2305277.9, 1390599.25
x2,y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
print (x2, y2)
```

...but I keep getting the same error.

```
b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

After some digging, I've discovered it is possible that either a) my pyproj hasn't installed correctly, or b) epsg:8826 may not exist with pyproj, but I can't seem to confirm / deny this.  I'm using Pycharm as my environment, and Anaconda for my python.

I tried following the advice at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390492/runtimeerror-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list) of changing my 'datadir.py' to ".../Anaconda3/Library/share", but to no luck.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use pyproj 2+?

Answer (score 0):

So following the logic provided by a comment from snowman2, I found there was some trouble between anaconda and pip with the version of pyproj I was using.  I was able to uninstall it all and a reinstall to the newest version of pyproj, which fixed my issues.