# RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list' (folium)

Tags: python, runtime-error, folium, pyproj

I have a problem, that I saw in several other questions : the following error message

```
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

when I execute this code :

```
m = folium.Map([43.7,7.2], zoom_start=12, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(my_geodataframe.boundary).add_to(m)
```

I tried several things I saw in other pages like this one [RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390492/runtimeerror-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list) :

- To update pyproj to version 2.4.0. However, I can't update to another version than 1.9.6 without having problems with geopandas. It forces me to reinstall geopandas, and then geopandas reinstall pyproj 1.9.6.
- To edit the path in "datadir.py". But pyproj_datadir="C:/Anaconda3\Library\share" doesn't improve things, and with "" instead of "/", it can't be read.

Any idea of something else to try ?

Comment: #Elise1369 were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Hm, I hadn't tried again, but now it works ! Perhaps because I created since a virtual env (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328395/python-pip-install-error-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified)